# How to GET to https with function ssh2_tunnel in php?

Tags: php

```
if ($tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection,'ipinfo.io', 80)){
$request = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n".
            "Host: ipinfo.io\r\n".
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0\r\n".
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n".
            "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n".
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n".
            "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

fwrite($tunnel, $request);

$result = '';

while (!feof($tunnel)) {
    $result .= fgets($tunnel);
}

echo $result;}
```

With the above code, I can GET to http://ipinfo.io and get its html content. However, I get nothing for https page(eg:https://www.google.com). How can I get html content of https page?

Comment: Https works on port 443. Did you try to just change the port from 80 to 443?

Comment: I tried but it responses a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

there is a special package available for ssh access in php,
you can visit it at
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html
they provide login and secure tunnel option

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please give me an example how to GET to https://www.facebook.com using that library?

Comment: can u describe me your purpose? means what you want to achieve then i will be able to guide you better.. :) because facebook.com you can get using file_get_contents('http://facebook.com'); also

Comment: I used to use curl and file_get_contents but they have some limitation, that's why I need to use my above method. Do you have any other idea?